# Munin plugins for Elasticsearch v2.x

Tags: munin, elasticsearch

Are there any Munin plugins available for Elasticsearch v2.x?

I know that [there are some for v1.x](https://github.com/y-ken/munin-plugin-elasticsearch) but these are not compatible with v2.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

> Munin plugin for monitoring elasticsearch 2.x nodes, including query
>   cache stats, document count, garbage collection, JVM heap stats,
>   request rates, and store size.
>
> Supported Modes
>
> - cache - query cache stats
> - docs - document count / deleted document count
> - gc - GC collections/sec (young, old)
> - gc_time - GC collection running time in ms (young, old)
> - jvm - JVM heap stats / survivor, young, old
> - ops - index, get, search, delete, merges operations/sec
> - store - size of index

https://github.com/t-cyrill/munin-elasticsearch2

Comment: While your answer may actually _answer_ the question, it feels more like it should have been a comment.  Could you perchance expound on the contents of the URL?  Or perhaps maybe share your own experience using the plugin you mentioned and list the pros and cons, or maybe list a couple different plugins that perform the same task and compare all of them to give the OP a rundown of the available options?